# UITableview Not displaying all the array records

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, storyboard

I am trying to display TableView records using Storyboard custom table but tableview is only displaying the first row of the array and not the others.

The data in the array is:

> <__NSArrayM 0x7a8cf910>(
>   Parts Shipping:  Included, Next Day 10:30 AM LST-GENERAL-US - 44,
>   Non-Usage Based,
>   M-F 0700-2200-US,
>   0328609 MSA - 2012- 0
>   )
>   ,
>
> <__NSArrayM 0x7a8cf940>(
>   1 Hour Travel Before/After FE Coverage M-F 0800-2100-US - 45,
>   Non-Usage Based,
>   M-F 0700-2200-US,
>   0328609 MSA - 2012- 0
>   )

The code I am using to display the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is as follows:

```
    static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"CellIdent";

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if(indexPath.row < [entitlements count])
    {
        finalDataArray = [entitlements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    UILabel *firstRowLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   firstRowLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 250, 54);
   firstRowLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   firstRowLabel.text =  [finalDataArray objectAtIndex:0];
   firstRowLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   firstRowLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
   firstRowLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:firstRowLabel];

    UIImageView *seperator1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(251, 0, 1, 47))];
   seperator1.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-header-separators.png"]];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:seperator1];

    UILabel *secondRowLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   secondRowLabel.frame = CGRectMake(252, 0, 300, 54);
   secondRowLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   secondRowLabel.text =  [finalDataArray objectAtIndex:1];
   secondRowLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   secondRowLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
   secondRowLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:secondRowLabel];       

    UIImageView *seperator2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(552, 0, 1, 47))];
   seperator2.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-header-separators.png"]];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:seperator2];

   UILabel *thirdRowLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   thirdRowLabel.frame = CGRectMake(553, 0,280 , 54);
   thirdRowLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   thirdRowLabel.text =  [finalDataArray objectAtIndex:2];
   thirdRowLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   thirdRowLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
   thirdRowLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:thirdRowLabel];

    UIImageView *seperator3 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(840, 0, 1, 47))];
   seperator3.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-header-separators.png"]];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:seperator3];

    UILabel *fourthRowLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   fourthRowLabel.frame = CGRectMake(841, 0,180 , 54);
   fourthRowLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   fourthRowLabel.text =  [finalDataArray objectAtIndex:3];
   fourthRowLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   fourthRowLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
   fourthRowLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:fourthRowLabel];
```

But its only displaying the first 4 values of `array1` and not the next 4.

Can you pls guide me as to what can be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: please show me your numberOfRowsInSection method

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection is `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return [entitlementData count];
}`

Comment: I am creating the finalArray which contains the values I need to show dynamically... entitlementData is the original multidimension array from which I am generating finalArray.

Comment: Send me your view controller file, it could be more complicated

Comment: @MitchellCurrie: Can you send me your email id? I can send the controller

Comment: Try a paste bin. We can take this to chat if you like

Comment: Try this: http://pastebin.com/rVYh23CR

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in the implementation of your UITableView, theses are the things to remember when implementing UITableView:

- add protocol **UITableViewDelegate** and **UITableViewDataSource**
- add two datasource methods: **tableView:numberOfRowsInSection** and **tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath**
- make sure the connection **Outlets** (delegate & datasource) in *Connections Inspector*
- **Don't forget** to name the appropriate UITableViewCell Identifier in your Storyboard (must be the same identifier in your *cellForRowAtIndexPath*)

Answer (score 0):

check your **numberOfRowsInSection** and **numberOfSectionsInTableView** and use **indexPath.row** or **indexPath.section** according to it.

Comment: `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}`